# Is there a way to prevent Facebook SDK from collecting the IP address?

Tags: android, ios, facebook

In this developer FAQ Facebook is stating, that they're collecting the client IP address when using the Facebook SDK:

[Facebook GDPR Developer FAQs](https://www.facebook.com/business/m/one-sheeters/gdpr-developer-faqs)

I couldn't find any information if it is possible to prevent this or anonymize the IP like you're able in Analytics for Firebase for example.

Am I overseeing something or do I have to live with the fact that Facebook is collecting my users IP addresses? I'm specifically interested in the Android and iOS SDKs.

Comment: If you communicate with a server then it is going to see your IP address; otherwise it wouldn't be able to send packets back.  Facebook could choose to obfuscate the IP address or not record it in logs, but there is nothing you can do on your side.

Comment: So I'm also not missing a setting on the Facebook for Developers dashboard?